# (Java) How to Build an array from a BufferedReader input reading data from an arduino board

Tags: java, arrays, arduino

I'm trying to read humidity and temperature data from an arduino board.

Currently it is outputting a simple integer caught by the bufferedreader and also the integer split to the temperature and humidity

Basically the output looks like this:

2021

20

21

2023

20

23

Running for a while, endlessly capturing the output of the arduino board and printing it out.

Here is the what the whole program looks like

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier; 
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEvent; 
import gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener; 
import java.util.Enumeration;


public class SerialTest implements SerialPortEventListener {


SerialPort serialPort;
    /** The port we're normally going to use. */
private static final String PORT_NAMES[] = { 
        "/dev/tty.usbserial-A9007UX1", // Mac OS X
                    "/dev/ttyACM0", // Raspberry Pi
        "/dev/ttyUSB0", // Linux
        "COM5", // Windows
};
/**
* A BufferedReader which will be fed by a InputStreamReader 
* converting the bytes into characters 
* making the displayed results codepage independent
*/
private BufferedReader input;
/** The output stream to the port */
private OutputStream output;
/** Milliseconds to block while waiting for port open */
private static final int TIME_OUT = 2000;
/** Default bits per second for COM port. */
private static final int DATA_RATE = 9600;

public void initialize() {
            // the next line is for Raspberry Pi and 
            // gets us into the while loop and was suggested here was suggested http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=81&t=32186
            //System.setProperty("gnu.io.rxtx.SerialPorts", "/dev/ttyACM0");

    CommPortIdentifier portId = null;
    Enumeration portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

    //First, Find an instance of serial port as set in PORT_NAMES.
    while (portEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
        CommPortIdentifier currPortId = (CommPortIdentifier) portEnum.nextElement();
        for (String portName : PORT_NAMES) {
            if (currPortId.getName().equals(portName)) {
                portId = currPortId;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (portId == null) {
        System.out.println("Could not find COM port.");
        return;
    }

    try {
        // open serial port, and use class name for the appName.
        serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open(this.getClass().getName(),
                TIME_OUT);

        // set port parameters
        serialPort.setSerialPortParams(DATA_RATE,
                SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

        // open the streams
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serialPort.getInputStream()));
        output = serialPort.getOutputStream();

        // add event listeners
        serialPort.addEventListener(this);
        serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.toString());
    }
}

/**
 * This should be called when you stop using the port.
 * This will prevent port locking on platforms like Linux.
 */
public synchronized void close() {
    if (serialPort != null) {
        serialPort.removeEventListener();
        serialPort.close();
    }
}

/**
 * Handle an event on the serial port. Read the data and print it.
 */
public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
    if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
        try {



            //output the BufferReader Input as Integer
            int number = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
            System.out.println(number);

            //Separate the input at a integer into the temperature and humidity.
            int Temp = number / 100;
            int Humidity = number % 100;    

            System.out.println(Temp);
            System.out.println(Humidity);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }



    }
    // Ignore all the other eventTypes, but you should consider the other ones.

}



public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SerialTest main = new SerialTest();
    main.initialize();
    Thread t=new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            //the following line will keep this app alive for 1000 seconds,
            //waiting for events to occur and responding to them (printing incoming messages to console).
            try {Thread.sleep(1000000);} catch (InterruptedException ie) {}


        }
    };
    t.start();
    System.out.println("Started");


}
}
```

Here is the portion that handles an event and prints out the recieved information

```
/**
 * Handle an event on the serial port. Read the data and print it.
 */
public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
    if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
        try {



            //output the BufferReader Input as Integer
            int number = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
            System.out.println(number);

            //Separate the input at a integer into the temperature and humidity.
            int Temp = number / 100;
            int Humidity = number % 100;    

            System.out.println(Temp);
            System.out.println(Humidity);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }



    }
    // Ignore all the other eventTypes, but you should consider the other ones.

}
```

Instead I would like to capture the temp and humidity into two separate arrays and incrementally build them till I can just print an array after capturing  10 outputs.

Honestly this is mostly borrowed code. It would be even better if I could have this entire class run inside another one, but I'm terribly new at this.

Answer (score 0):

You need some place to store the collected numbers and print them when enough of them are received. Just add two member variables that are holding the data:

```
    private List<Integer> temperatures = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Integer> humidities = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then collect and print them as follows:

```
        temperatures.add(number / 100);
        humidities.add(number % 100);
        if(humidities.size() >= 10) {
            System.out.println(temperatures);
            System.out.println(humidities);
            // clear both lists
            temperatures.clear();
            humidities.clear();
        }
```

As a slight modification you can also use a single collection storing  just the parsed numbers and do the temperature/humidity calculation when printing the numbers.